# How do I make the placeholder not go away?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm going to use a textarea to leave comments, but I wanted it to never disappear so I thought about saving it in the database and so when it comes to bringing, using the placeholder, but today if I type something over it it replaces the things that are in the placeholder and I would like you to enter and start typing without affecting the placeholder

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <label for="obs">Obs:</label>
  <textarea
    class="form-control"
    name="obs"
    rows="5"
    placeholder="aaaaaaaaaaa"
  ></textarea>
  <button type="submit" class="mt-2 btn btn-primary" name="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: So you would like the content to be editable in the textarea or?

Comment: I'll give you an example, I added a note, will update the database and thus return as a placeholder, but what is in the placeholder cannot be edited.

Comment: But that is the point, right? If you add the new data as placeholder? I am bit confused about with the problem is?

Comment: Placeholders are not made to be edited. Do you simply want to provide a _default value_ for the textarea here, that the user can then edit/modify/delete? Well that is done by putting that content between the opening and closing textarea tag - `<textarea>I am the default content of this textarea, the user can edit me</textarea>`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it isn't possible to always show the placeholder. However you could use this little trick to fake it. I hope this is what you mean.

```
    <style>
      .placeholder {
         position: absolute;
         margin-left: 5px;
         opacity: .5;
       }
    </style>
    
    <form action="" method="post">
       <label for="obs">Obs:</label>
       <div>
        <span class="placeholder">aaaaaaa</span>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="obs" rows="5"></textarea>
       </div>
      <button type="submit" class="mt-2 btn btn-primary" name="button">Save</button>
    </form>
```